# Call anonymous function on object

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, anonymous-function

Normally I do callbacks like this: The **Object that invokes the callback** has this methods:

```
this.set_success_callback = function(obj, func){
    this.success_callback_obj  = obj;
    this.success_callback_func = func;
}

this.make_success_callback = function(msg){
    this.success_callback_obj[this.success_callback_func](msg);
}
```

Then In When I setup the **Object** I assgin the callback like this:

```
 var obj = new ...
     obj.set_success_callback(this, "sayHello");
```

This works as expected. **But when I want to define the callback like this:**

```
  obj.set_success_callback(this, this.sayHello);
```

And change the `make_success_callback` function to:

```
 this.success_callback_ob.call(this.success_callback_func, msg)
```

**I get this error:**

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'call'
```

**What do I have to change to make it work? How can I invoke the function sayHello on this? Thanks**

Comment: So many unknowns in the question. Can you please provide a minimal reproducible program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just mixed up the object with the function.  It should be:

```
this.success_callback_func.call(this.success_callback_ob, msg)
```

A `Function` has a [`.call()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), that takes a context object as the first argument.  `Object` has no `.call()` method.

Comment: Thanks, Although I read the docs I didnt got it correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call